# Calculation Percentage Remainder

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to auto calculate the remainder percentage from 4 dropdown select option.  This is the code I have so far, but I can't seem to get it to work.  After the calculation, the undeveloped percentage should be the total percentage added up minus 100%.  For example, if each of the 4 had 10% used, the Undeveloped would be 60%.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Calculation</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function calcPercentUseSum(){
var Percent1 = document.getElementsByName("SingleFamilyUsePercent");
var strUser = Percent1.options[Percent1.selectedIndex].value;
var Percent2 = document.getElementsByName("MultifamilyUsePercent");
var strUser = Percent2.options[Percent2.selectedIndex].value;
var Percent3 = document.getElementsByName("CommericalUsePercent");
var strUser = Percent3.options[Percent3.selectedIndex].value;
var Percent4 = document.getElementsByName("IndustrialUsePercent");
var strUser = Percent4.options[Percent4.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementsByName("Undeveloped").value = Percent1
                        + Percent2
                        + Percent3
                        + Percent4;
}




</script>






</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action>




<table width="640">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <th rowspan="3" colspan="3" valign="bottom" align="left">&nbsp;Present Use:</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 21px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="height: 21px"></td>        
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3" align="left" style="height: 18px">&nbsp;</th>                
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 25px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" style="height: 25px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="height: 25px">Single Family</td>
    <td style="height: 25px"><select size="1" name="SingleFamilyUsePercent" 
     onchange="calcPercentUseSum" value="Single Family" tabindex="92">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0%">0%</option>
        <option value="5%">5%</option>
        <option value="10%">10%</option>
        <option value="15%">15%</option>
        <option value="20%">20%</option>
        <option value="25%">25%</option>
        <option value="30%">30%</option>
        <option value="35%">35%</option>
        <option value="40%">40%</option>
        <option value="45%">45%</option>
        <option value="50%">50%</option>
        <option value="55%">55%</option>
        <option value="60%">60%</option>
        <option value="65%">65%</option>
        <option value="70%">70%</option>
        <option value="75%">75%</option>
        <option value="80%">80%</option>
        <option value="85%">85%</option>
        <option value="90%">90%</option>
        <option value="95%">95%</option>
        <option value="100%">100%</option>
      </select></td>                
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Multifamily</td>
    <td><select size="1" name="MultifamilyUsePercent" onchange="calcPercentUseSum"
 value="Multifamily" tabindex="93">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0%">0%</option>
        <option value="5%">5%</option>
        <option value="10%">10%</option>
        <option value="15%">15%</option>
        <option value="20%">20%</option>
        <option value="25%">25%</option>
        <option value="30%">30%</option>
        <option value="35%">35%</option>
        <option value="40%">40%</option>
        <option value="45%">45%</option>
        <option value="50%">50%</option>
        <option value="55%">55%</option>
        <option value="60%">60%</option>
        <option value="65%">65%</option>
        <option value="70%">70%</option>
        <option value="75%">75%</option>
        <option value="80%">80%</option>
        <option value="85%">85%</option>
        <option value="90%">90%</option>
        <option value="95%">95%</option>
        <option value="100%">100%</option>
      </select></td>                
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Commericial</td>
    <td><select size="1" name="CommericalUsePercent" onchange="calcPercentUseSum"  
 value="Commericial" tabindex="94">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0%">0%</option>
        <option value="5%">5%</option>
        <option value="10%">10%</option>
        <option value="15%">15%</option>
        <option value="20%">20%</option>
        <option value="25%">25%</option>
        <option value="30%">30%</option>
        <option value="35%">35%</option>
        <option value="40%">40%</option>
        <option value="45%">45%</option>
        <option value="50%">50%</option>
        <option value="55%">55%</option>
        <option value="60%">60%</option>
        <option value="65%">65%</option>
        <option value="70%">70%</option>
        <option value="75%">75%</option>
        <option value="80%">80%</option>
        <option value="85%">85%</option>
        <option value="90%">90%</option>
        <option value="95%">95%</option>
        <option value="100%">100%</option>
      </select></td>        
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Industrial</td>
    <td><b>
    <select size="1" name="IndustrialUsePercent" onchange="calcPercentUseSum"
value="Industrial" tabindex="95" style="height: 21px">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0%">0%</option>
        <option value="5%">5%</option>
        <option value="10%">10%</option>
        <option value="15%">15%</option>
        <option value="20%">20%</option>
        <option value="25%">25%</option>
        <option value="30%">30%</option>
        <option value="35%">35%</option>
        <option value="40%">40%</option>
        <option value="45%">45%</option>
        <option value="50%">50%</option>
        <option value="55%">55%</option>
        <option value="60%">60%</option>
        <option value="65%">65%</option>
        <option value="70%">70%</option>
        <option value="75%">75%</option>
        <option value="80%">80%</option>
        <option value="85%">85%</option>
        <option value="90%">90%</option>
        <option value="95%">95%</option>
        <option value="100%">100%</option>
      </select></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Undeveloped</td>
    <td><input name="Undeveloped" readonly="readonly" type="text"  /></td>
  </tr>
</table><br />

<input type="submit" value="Save Form" name="tbSubmit" tabindex="253" />


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at your function. You're fetching the proper value from each of the `<select>` options, but then you're storing the result in a variable called `strUser` which you've [re]declared 4 times. You're overwriting the value, and then not even using it.

You're trying to sum (using +) the actual HTML `<select>` elements, rather than the selected values you're (trying) to pull out.

Assign the values to *separate* variables, and then cast them to integers. I would remove the "%" sign off the `value` attributes in your HTML so they're easier to work with. Once you've done that then you essentially just have to do

```
var Percent1 = document.getElementsByName("SingleFamilyUsePercent")[0];
var Value1 = Percent1.options[Percent1.selectedIndex].value;
var Percent2 = document.getElementsByName("MultifamilyUsePercent")[0];
var Value2 = Percent2.options[Percent2.selectedIndex].value;
...
var Total = parseInt(Value1) + parseInt(Value2);
var Remainder = 100 - Total;

document.getElementsByName("Undeveloped")[0].value = Remainder;
```

I put `[0]`s on there because (I'm pretty sure) `getElementsByName` returns a *list* of elements, rather than a single one. Really, you should prefer to give your inputs `ID` attributes and then use `getElementById` instead.

Comment: Just noting that Mark is right - getElementsByName will return an array, which needs to be dereferenced. Additionally, instead of having the percentage sign within the value attribute, you probably want to just put the integer there. That's why the value attribute exists, so you can have tags of the form `<option value="realvalue">Display Value</option>`.

Comment: When the calc function fires and one of the `select` elements has the `""` value selected, then `parseInt("")` will return `NaN`, which will then throw off the total; `NaN + 50 + 5 + 10` will return `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example that builds on some of the suggestions mentioned in previous answers:

http://jsfiddle.net/wdqgF/

**JavaScript**

```
calcPercentUseSum = function () {
    var Use1 = document.getElementById("SingleFamilyUsePercent"),
        Use2 = document.getElementById("MultifamilyUsePercent"),
        Use3 = document.getElementById("CommericalUsePercent"),
        Use4 = document.getElementById("IndustrialUsePercent");

    var Perc1 = Use1.options[Use1.selectedIndex].value,
        Perc2 = Use2.options[Use2.selectedIndex].value,
        Perc3 = Use3.options[Use3.selectedIndex].value,
        Perc4 = Use4.options[Use4.selectedIndex].value;

    function cleanVal(n) {
        // You do not want to call parseInt on an empty string "".
        // parseInt("") will return NaN, 
        // and NaN plus a number will return NaN. 
        // e.g., "NaN + 5 + 10 + 20" returns NaN. Avoid this.
        if (n === "") {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return parseInt(n, 10);
        }
    }

    var sumPerc = cleanVal(Perc1) + cleanVal(Perc2) + cleanVal(Perc3) + cleanVal(Perc4); 

    var Total = function () {
        if ( Perc1 === "" && Perc2 === "" && Perc3 === "" && Perc4 === "" ) {
            // To cover the scenario where the user selects item(s), 
            // but then reverts all items back to their first/empty option 
            return "";
        } else if ( sumPerc > 100 ) {
            // To cover the case where the Present Use Totals exceed 100%.
            return "0%";    
        } else {
            return (100 - sumPerc) + "%";
        }
    };

    document.getElementById("Undeveloped").value = Total();
};
```

Note how in each `<select>`, an `id` is now present.

**sample from altered HTML**

```
    <select size="1" name="SingleFamilyUsePercent" id="SingleFamilyUsePercent"
    onchange="calcPercentUseSum()" value="Single Family" tabindex="92">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">0%</option>
...
```